# How do I hook up my Hibernate 4 interceptor in Java configuration for Spring 3?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Hibernate interceptor that I want to put on the onLoad() call for Hibernate. I'm doing this because I want a JPA entity to have an instance of SecureRandom injected into it by Spring. Since the JPA context and the Spring context do not mix, this is a bridge from the Spring context into the JPA context.

I have "two places" in my Java config where I setup the stuff for Hibernate 4. I've included their enteries below. According to this (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8940) I think that to set the Hibernate interceptor programmatically I need to get access to the LocalSessionFactoryBean. Perhaps through the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean? I just have no idea how to do that, or if I need to reconfigure the way I'm setting up my Hibernate stuff. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
@Bean
JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}

@Bean(name = "LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory")
@Autowired
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(BasicDataSource jdbcConnection) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(jdbcConnection);
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(this.getClass().getPackage().getName());

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);
    return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
}


@Component
public class InvitationEntityInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    @Autowired
    SecureRandom secureRandom;
    @Override
    public boolean onLoad(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        if(entity instanceof Invitation) {
            Invitation invitation = (Invitation) entity;
            invitation.setRandom(secureRandom);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned the approach of using some hibernate specific event based solution and instead went for using @Configuration which requires aspectJ in Spring.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

> 9.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring
>
> The Spring container instantiates and configures beans defined in your
>   application context. It is also possible to ask a bean factory to
>   configure a pre-existing object given the name of a bean definition
>   containing the configuration to be applied. The spring-aspects.jar
>   contains an annotation-driven aspect that exploits this capability to
>   allow dependency injection of any object. The support is intended to
>   be used for objects created outside of the control of any container.
>   Domain objects often fall into this category because they are often
>   created programmatically using the new operator, or by an ORM tool as
>   a result of a database query.
>
> The @Configurable annotation marks a class as eligible for
>   Spring-driven configuration. In the simplest case it can be used just
>   as a marker annotation:

Answer (score 2):

I've managed this that way:

Spring database configuration class:

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("hibernateInterceptor")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        DataSource dataSource,
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter,
        HibernateInterceptor hibernateInterceptor) {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    ...
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor", hibernateInterceptor);
    emfb.setJpaProperties(props);
    return emfb;
}
```

Hibernate interceptor class:

```
@Component
public class HibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;
    ...
}
```